# C# - For loop iterator suddenly increasing inside loop

Tags: .net, multithreading, tcp, thread-safety

I'm making a TCP Server in C#, and I have these few codes:

**TCP Server:**

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           Server.Bind(Self);
           Server.Listen(10);
           Accept = new Thread(HandleClients);
           Receive = new Thread(HandleMessages);
           Accept.Start();
           Receive.Start();
      }
      void HandleClients()
      {
           while (true)
           {
                AllUsers.Add(new Participant(Server.Accept()));
           }
      }
      void HandleMessages()
      {
           while (true)
           {
                int Count = AllUsers.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
                {
                     if (AllUsers[i].Socket.Available > 0)
                     {
                          byte[] Data = new byte[1500];
                          AllUsers[i].Socket.Receive(Data); // i == 0 right here
                          Thread handle = new Thread(() => HandleInput(Data, AllUsers[i])); // all of the sudden i==1 right here
                          handle.Start();
                     }
                     Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1);
           }
      }
```

**TCP Client:**

```
private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
               Client.Connect(Server);
               Send("0x01" + "!" + usernameText.Text); // Send username
               ReceiveThread = new Thread(Receive);
               ReceiveThread.Start();
          }
```

The server code, as you see, is intended to accept and handle multiple TCP connections without using asynchronous I/O (I'm using the Socket.Available property to check for data instead).

So when somebody connects, the server sometimes crashes. When a user connects he sends his username right after connecting, and this causes the server to open a new thread to handle the user's packet.

So sometimes, when someone connects and sends his username (the username sending happens immediately after connecting), the server crashes at the IF area inside the FOR loop. The crash happens at the part where a new thread is created with a lambda expression - somehow, sometimes the iterator of the FOR loop (i) increases by 1 for no apparent reason, and this causes an ArgumentOutOfRangeException to be thrown.

For example, before anyone connects, the list's count is 0. When someone connects, he is immediately being added to the user list, increasing its count from 0 to 1. Now, the FOR loop finally starts working after he connected, but sometimes something weird happens. At the Receive line, the variable i is equal to 0, and that line receives the byte array and puts it into the Data variable. In the next line, a new thread is created, and the current user object (AllUsers[i]) is being passed to it as a parameter. But what's weird is that sometimes when the parameter is passed, the variable i somehow becomes equals to 1, and as a result an exception is being thrown.

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening? I think it's something with the multithreading that went wrong but I'm not sure what.

Thanks,

-BlueRay101-

Comment: You need to monitor accesses of shared resources through locks. In this case, the list AllUsers is accessed from multiple threads concurrently. Use e.g. `lock(AllUsers) { ... }`

Comment: If you increase the first thread.sleep value to more then 50 that might work. The loop continued on one side. While the thread started running other side.

Comment: OK, Thank you, I understand I should use locks, and also increasing it to 50 isn't an option because the speed here is critical. But I still can't figure it out: How could it be that the iterator has changed in the middle of the loop? Could it be that the other thread changed the loop's iterator? And if not, what could've increased the iterator in the middle of the loop?